# Preserve quotes with yq

Tags: yaml, yq

I have the following yq command

```
yq e '.values.tags="{tag1:'value1', tag2:'value2'}"' -i my file.yaml
```

I need the values to be quoted.
When I run the query with yq, the quotes arround the values are removed. I tried a couple of things to remove them, but so far nothing works.

In my yaml file, it ends up like this:

```
values:
    tags: "{tag1:value1, tag2:value2}"
```

While i expect this:

```
values:
    tags: "{tag1:'value1', tag2:'value2'}"
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you

Comment: The question is why? Having it as `"{tag1:value1, tag2:value2}"` is a proper YAML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single quotes are interpreted by your shell. Shells concatenate quoted and non-quoted adjacent values. From the shell's view, you're giving the following adjacent values:

```
.values.tags="{tag1:
value1
, tag2:
value2
}"
```

These are concatenated and the result is what you're seeing.

There are several possibilities to remedy this. I suggest to use double quotes at shell level for the value:

```sh
yq e ".values.tags=\"{tag1:'value1', tag2:'value2'}\"" -i myfile.yaml
```

This way, you only need to escape the double quotes in the string. (This does not work in csh/tcsh.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the from_json and to_json operators in yq to edit it all inplace:

```sh
yq e '.values.tags |= (from_yaml | .tag1 = "cat" | to_json(0))' file.yaml
```

See https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/encode-decode for more info.

Disclosure: I wrote yq

Comment: Welcome to answering the site's `yq` tag questions. FYI - Do look up https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior for some information about disclosure. I guess the original authors must state so, while suggesting answers from the tools they wrote

Comment: Oh didn't know that, thanks.

Comment: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67302382/5291015

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @flyx. The solution you mentioned helped me to fix my issue. I had a requirement to convert yaml to json, modify and then again convert it back to yaml.

This is how I did:

```
cat abc.yaml | sed -e 's,\",\\",g' | yq eval -j | jq . > bca.json
jq -e '(.spec.template.spec.volumes[1]) = "" '  bca.json | sponge bca.json
yq eval -P bca.json > bca.yaml
sed -i -e 's,\\",\",g' bca.yaml
```