# Rename JSON key after a specific pattern

Tags: python, awk, sed

I have a JSON object with the following content:

```
{
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "id": "77",
            "q1": {
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                "options": [
                    "New York Bulls",
                    "Huston Rocket"
                ],
                "answer": "Huston Rocket"
            }
        },
        "maths": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "10",
                    "13"
                ],
                "answer": "13"
            },
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to look for the KEY "id". And once is found, to start looking for the KEY "answer" and rename it to "answer_id".

Expected output:

```
{
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "id": "77",
            "q1": {
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                "options": [
                    "New York Bulls",
                    "Huston Rocket"
                ],
                "answer_id": "Huston Rocket"
            }
        },
        "maths": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "10",
                    "13"
                ],
                "answer": "12"
            },
           
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried this so far what doesn't catch the field correctly:

```
awk   ' { for ( i = 1; i <= NF; ++i ) {

              if ( $i == "id" )
                  r = 1

              if ( r && $i == "answer")
                  $i = "answer_id" 
                  r = 0           
            }
          }
          1 ' example.json > example2.json
```

Comment: Hi! If I will get you a solution this problem with using python. Will it help you?

Comment: Yes!! @AndreiGurko

Comment: I have posted my solution just now. Please, try it))

Comment: Is there always one question i.e. `q1` or there will be multiple questions expected?

Comment: There will be multiples q1. I mean this is the structure but the keys will appear more than once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, one of solutions...

```
data = {
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "id": "77",
            "q1": {
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                "options": [
                    "New York Bulls",
                    "Huston Rocket"
                ],
                "answer": "Huston Rocket"
            }
        },
        "maths": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "10",
                    "13"
                ],
                "answer": "13"
            },
        }
    }
}

for key in data.get('quiz'):
    inner_data = data['quiz'][key]
    if 'id' in inner_data and 'answer' in inner_data['q1']:
        inner_data['q1']['answer_id'] = inner_data['q1'].pop('answer')

print(data)
```

Comment: Is there any option to mantein the order from the original?

Comment: @Max sorry, but I am not understand you. You mean how save the value of inner_data['q1'].pop('answer') or something else?

Comment: I mean when I execute my code in a VM it gives me in the first place 'maths' instead of 'sport'

Comment: @ Max, sanks for explanation. So data is a dict structure, and dict doesnt guarantee that keys will be all time for currents position. But from python3.7 I read that, dict guarantees order of keys.

Comment: And how would you rename the tag 'quiz' to 'data1'

Answer (score 0):

A jq solution which preserves the key order:

```
walk(if type=="object" and .id
  then walk(if type=="object" and .answer 
    then  with_entries(if .key=="answer"
      then .key+="_id" else . end)
    else . end)
  else . end)
```

or maybe you want:

```
walk(if type=="object" and .id
  then .id |= walk(if type=="object" and .answer 
    then  with_entries(if .key=="answer"
      then .key+="_id" else . end)
    else . end)
  else . end)
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit?

Comment: @Max - Consider {"id": 0, "answer": 1}

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Are you using jq?

Comment: @Max - Please see the first line of your Q, and the first line of my A.

Answer (score 0):

here's a `jtc` based solution for the same JSON query (assuming source JSON is in `file.json`):

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -w'<id>l:[-1]<answer>l:<>k' -u'"answer_id"'
```

as simple as that.

PS. it so happens that I'm a developer of `jtc` - JSON multithreading processing tool for unix
PPS. the above disclaimer is a requirement of the SO

Comment: This is not valid to my case. Any idea to do it by jq? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Max, jq solution was provided by peak