# yq escape single quotes wit hin double quotes

Tags: yaml, yq

I am using the [yq portable command-line YAML processor](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) (version 4.27.3 on an Ubuntu machine) to add a new value into a yaml-file.

The best try I have is this one:

example.yaml:

```
- name: Kubernetes Apps | Install ArgoCD
  become: yes
  kube:
    name: ArgoCD
    kubectl: "{{ bin_dir }}/kubectl"
    filename: "{{ kube_config_dir }}/{{ item.file }}"
    state: latest
  with_items: "{{ argocd_templates }}"
  when:
    - "inventory_hostname == groups['kube_control_plane'][0]"
```

yq-Command:

```
yq -i '(.[] | select(.name ==  "Kubernetes Apps | Install ArgoCD") | .with_items) = "{{ argocd_templates | rejectattr('name', 'eq', 'bootstrap') | list }}"' example.yaml
```

Output in yaml-file:

```
with_items: "{{ argocd_templates | rejectattr(name, eq, bootstrap) | list }}"
```

I would like to achieve this output:

```
with_items: "{{ argocd_templates | rejectattr(‘name’, ‘eq’, ‘bootstrap’) | list }}"
```

The difference are the single quotes within the double quotes.
I tried to escape the quotes with backslashes or to use triple single quotes ( like ‘’’name’’‘ or \’name\’).
Unfortunately, I have no success with this and then either still have no single quotes or an invalid input.

I would like to solve this issue with the yq-tool because I already use it for other yaml-file modifications.

Does anybody have an idea how to get the single quotes in place?

Answer (score 0):

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67192318/7244882) in another post.

The command with the desired output looks like this:

```
   yq -i "(.[] | select(.name ==  \"Kubernetes Apps | Install ArgoCD\") | .with_items) = \"{{ argocd_templates | rejectattr('name', 'eq', 'bootstrap') | list }}\"" example.yml
```